# Syntax to check whether the data is right or not (systemverilog)

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, verification, uvm

I wanna create the task that verifies the output is correct or not. If it is correct it shows correct +1 and if there would be an error it shows error +1. By writing this code, I couldn't get any value in expected123.

```
logic [31:0] expected123;
task checker123 (logic [31:0] expected, logic [31:0] actual, bit [3:0] command, logic[31:0] input1, input2);
  $display("%h, %h, %h, %h, %h", expected, actual, command, input1, input2); 

  if(command == "0001")
    expected123 = input1 + input2;
  $display(expected, input1, input2);

  if(command == "0010")
    expected123 = input1 - input2;
  $display(expected, input1, input2);

  expected = expected123;

  if (expected !== actual) begin
    $display("%t: command %h is expected %h but got %h ", $time, command, expected, actual);
    error = error + 1;
  end
  correct = correct + 1;
endtask
```

Comment: to instantiate this task
checker123(expected123 , topif.cb.out_data3, ADD,add1.a, add1.b);
where topif.out_data3 is actual output by circuit, add = 0001, add1.a and add1.b are random inputs generated by random.
I'm confused expected123. Is that okay to force this? any suggestions?

Comment: you are comparing 4-bit binary `command` with an 64-bit string `"0001"`.  this is not verilog.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You might be inadvertently writing VHDL syntax in Verilog. Should be

```
  if(command == 4'b0001)
```